# Mod Rewrite Optional Parameters

Tags: mod-rewrite, paging

I have a fairly complex set of rewrite rules to give my site pages pretty URLs. Right now to deal with paging of search results I'm using 2 rewrite rules:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([0-9]+)$ /cgi-bin/search.pl?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^search$ /cgi-bin/search.pl [NC,L,QSA]
```

These handle URLs such as:

```
http://example.com/search
http://example.com/search/2
http://example.com/search/1000
```

I'm wondering how to combine these into 1 rewrite rule so that the search.pl script is called correctly and only passed the page parameter if a page is specified. I know it's a pretty basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Looks like the first few answers are going a little bit in the wrong direction. I was thinking more along the lines of redoing the regex so that the page parameters are optional. Maybe something like:

RewriteRule ^search(/([0-9]+))?$ /cgi-bin/search.pl?page=$1 [NC,L,QSA]

But it needs to actually work.

Comment: @Russell C.: Replace the `$1` with `$2` as you want the match of the second parenthesis group.

Comment: There are two separate changes being made to the URL - (1) go to cgi-bin/search.pl and (2) if there's a page number, pass it as a parameter.  It's logical for this to be two RewriteRules.  Why do you want to make it one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
RewriteCond page=$2 ^page=.+|
RewriteRule ^search(/([0-9]+))?$ /cgi-bin/search.pl?%0 [NC,L,QSA]
```

But that’s not really nicer, is it?

---

**Edit**    Or if you’re fine with an empty *page* value:

```
RewriteRule ^search(/([0-9]+))?$ /cgi-bin/search.pl?page=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: That second one it is. Works like a charm. Thanks Gumbo!

Answer (score 0):

You *could* use [rewritemap](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) with a small external script which maps non-empty to `?page=$1` and empty to empty. I would suggest sticking with what you've got.